# how can I fix this error: no module named 'PIL' on Heroku cloud?

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I did create a project in Django and I installed everything Django needs to into the virtual environment now I upload the project on the Heroku cloud and when I try to upload any image I get message error: **No module named 'PIL'** so, I thought maybe I didn't install Pillow when I check on `pip3 freeze` I get a Pillow and the project locally works properly. 
so what is the real problem here and How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have a `requirements.txt`? How are you deploying to heroku exactly? You might need to just update your `requirements.txt` or `pipfile`, or whatever it is your using.

Comment: yes sure, I have requirements.txt and pip3, and website is working but this point is not working.

Comment: Have you updated your requirements.txt to include the dependency?